# object literal handling multiple instances

Tags: javascript, asp.net, user-controls, object-literal

My entire JavaScript library is constructed in an object literal namespace. It contains each page's logic from init() to common functions, controls, validation, etc. The page's init() function gets fired based on the page's body id.

The problem I have is in my controls section.  I have an object literal named AddressEntry.  This object literal contains the functionality that deals with my AddressEntry ASP.NET UserControl. It works just fine with one AddressEntry control on the page, but when there's more than one, only the last one on the page works as intended.

Here's my ***AddressEntry object literal*** (trimmed down to pertinent information):

```
SFAIC.ctrls.AddressEntry = {

    inputs : {

        city        : undefined,
        cityState   : undefined,

        hidden : {

            city    : undefined,
            state   : undefined

        },  

    },

    fn : {

        root : undefined,

        citySelected : function($ddl) {

            var $selected = $ddl.find(":selected");

            this.root.inputs.hidden.city.val($selected.val());          
            this.root.inputs.hidden.state.val($selected.text().split(", ")[1]);

        }

    },

    init : function(addressId) { 

        var self    = this,
            fn      = self.fn,
            inputs  = self.inputs,
            hidden  = inputs.hidden;

            inputs.city         = SFAIC.fn.getContentElement(addressId + "_ddlCity",                SFAIC.$updatePanel);
            inputs.cityState    = SFAIC.fn.getContentElement(addressId + "_ddlCityStateLocked",     SFAIC.$updatePanel);
            hidden.city         = SFAIC.fn.getContentElement(addressId + "_txtCity",                SFAIC.$updatePanel);
            hidden.state        = SFAIC.fn.getContentElement(addressId + "_txtState",               SFAIC.$updatePanel);

            fn.root = this;

        inputs.city.change(function() { fn.citySelected($(this)); });
        inputs.cityState.change(function() { fn.citySelected($(this)); });

    }

};
```

Then, the ***page object literal*** would look something like this (again, trimmed down):

```
SFAIC.pages.salesProcess.Applicant = {

    init : function() {         

        SFAIC.ctrls.AddressEntry.init("AddressGarage");
        SFAIC.ctrls.AddressEntry.init("AddressMailing");

    }

};
```

It's obvious to me that ***AddressMailing*** init overrides the ***AddressGarage*** init.  What can I do to objectify the ***SFAIC.ctrls.AddressEntry*** object literal to be able to handle as many AddressEntry UserControls that I may have on the page without them overriding each other?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: you are trying to initialize all of your AddressEntries (which are completely different objects or DOM elements) in a single function (init function of SFAIC.pages).

Comment: Basically. Since it's an ASP.NET UserControl, each instance of the UserControl renders the same elements with different prefix ids.  For example: AddressMailing_txtCity, AddressMailing_txtState, etc. in the AddressMailing control and AddressGarage_txtCity, AddressGarage_txtState in the AddressGarage control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I came up with:

```
SFAIC.ctrls.AddressEntry = function(addressId) {

    var ctrl = {

            inputs : {

                city        : undefined,
                cityState   : undefined,

                hidden : {

                    city    : undefined,
                    state   : undefined

                },  

            },

            fn : {

                root : undefined,

                citySelected : function($ddl) {

                    var $selected = $ddl.find(":selected");

                    this.root.inputs.hidden.city.val($selected.val());          
                    this.root.inputs.hidden.state.val($selected.text().split(", ")[1]);

                }

            },

            init : function(addressId) { 

                var self    = this,
                    fn      = self.fn,
                    inputs  = self.inputs,
                    hidden  = inputs.hidden;

                    inputs.city         = SFAIC.fn.getContentElement(addressId + "_ddlCity",                SFAIC.$updatePanel);
                    inputs.cityState    = SFAIC.fn.getContentElement(addressId + "_ddlCityStateLocked",     SFAIC.$updatePanel);
                    hidden.city         = SFAIC.fn.getContentElement(addressId + "_txtCity",                SFAIC.$updatePanel);
                    hidden.state        = SFAIC.fn.getContentElement(addressId + "_txtState",               SFAIC.$updatePanel);

                    fn.root = this;

                inputs.city.change(function() { fn.citySelected($(this)); });
                inputs.cityState.change(function() { fn.citySelected($(this)); });

            }

    };

    ctrl.init();

    return ctrl;    

};          

SFAIC.pages.salesProcess.Applicant = {

    init : function() {         

        var garage, mailing;

        garage = SFAIC.ctrls.AddressEntry("AddressGarage");
        mailing = SFAIC.ctrls.AddressEntry("AddressMailing");

    }

};
```

Answer (score 1):

An object literal is by definition a single instance of an object. Maybe you should be creating a object using prototypes that way you can create multiple instances of the same object.

A HACK would be to create a second object literal that is nearly the same but with a different name.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know if I'm late to post a possible solution, but here I go anyway.

I don't know your DOM structure or JS objects, but what I would do something like this:

1. Get the all DOM elements or JS objects of type AddressEntry, by some class or special attribute. You probably would have to change something elsewhere in order to achieve this.
2. Cycle each element and call the "init" function using "Call". That way each object or element would be bound to the initialization you are doing.

It would look something like this (not tested!!):

```
SFAIC.pages.salesProcess.Applicant = {

    init : function() {         

        $('.addresses').each(function (i) {
            SFAIC.ctrls.AddressEntry.init.call(this, this.attr('id'); });
    }
};
```

The code might be bugged or lacking  few more lines to make it work, but I think the idea is clear. Hope it helps and you can apply it to your case.